# How to convert a string time with milliseconds (hh:mm:ss.xxx) to time.Time?

Tags: go

Basically I have times like this one as a string:

```
15:56:36.113
```

I want to convert it to `time.Time`.

From what I am reading I cannot use milliseconds when using `time.Parse()`.

Is there another way to convert my string to `time.Time` ?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. It is asking about fractional seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Package time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/)
>
> Format Reference Time
>
> A decimal point followed by one or more zeros represents a fractional
>   second, printed to the given number of decimal places. A decimal point
>   followed by one or more nines represents a fractional second, printed
>   to the given number of decimal places, with trailing zeros removed.
>   When parsing (only), the input may contain a fractional second field
>   immediately after the seconds field, even if the layout does not
>   signify its presence. In that case a decimal point followed by a
>   maximal series of digits is parsed as a fractional second.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t, err := time.Parse("15:04:05", "15:56:36.113")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(t)

    fmt.Println(t.Format("15:04:05.000"))

    h, m, s := t.Clock()
    ms := t.Nanosecond() / int(time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Printf("%02d:%02d:%02d.%03d\n", h, m, s, ms)
}
```

Output:

```
0000-01-01 15:56:36.113 +0000 UTC
15:56:36.113
15:56:36.113
```

Note: The zero value of type Time is `0000-01-01 00:00:00.000000000 UTC`.

Answer (score 1):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    s := "15:56:36.113"
    t,_ := time.Parse("15:04:05.000", s)

    fmt.Print(t)
}
```

Output:

```
0000-01-01 15:56:36.113 +0000 UTC
```

You can play with it more here: https://play.golang.org/p/3A3e8zHQ8r